# How to install glassfish tools for glassfish 2.1 server in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-marketplace, glassfish-2.x

In the new versions of eclipse, glassfish server tools found in the Eclipse market only support **glassfish 3.1 and above**.

There is no support for **glassfish 2.1** in glassfish tools downloaded from the market for any version of Eclipse. I have tried several without success.

I have to maintain **glassfish 2.1 jee5** code.

Answer (score 0):

found there is oracle archive for bundles of all Oracle tools for eclipse.

the last version that supports glassfish 2.1 - is 12.1.1.2.1 - March 2013.

https://web.archive.org/web/20180603133732/http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/developer-tools/eclipse/downloads/oepe-archive-1716547.html

I downloaded oepe-12.1.1.2.1-kepler-repository.zip
then in to the new version of eclipse 2018-09 - 4.9 I installed from the repository
only glass fish tools - and it worked

Comment: Getting 404 for this link, is there any other way? I just need Glassfish full framework not web profile 2.1.1 zip file, not exe for window 10? Can some one help please?

Comment: you are in luck: archive.org has it.

https://web.archive.org/web/20180604180430/http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/developer-tools/eclipse/downloads/oepe-download-121121-1918582.html